# Copy Windows directory, including specified directory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cmd.exe, xcopy

I want to copy the directory itself, not only the contents.

For example I have

```
C:\DirA\SubDirA\FileA
```

I want to copy DirA into DirB so that I have

```
C:\DirB\DirA\SubDirA\FileA
```

Here's what I've tried

```
copy C:\DirA C:\DirB
xcopy C:\DirA C:\DirB /e /s
```

But whatever I try to do, DirA gets left out

```
C:\DirB\SubDirA\FileA
```

Note: I have a list of directories I want to copy, so I don't know the directory name beforehand and I can't afford to run a heavyweight program like robocopy 1,000 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try Powershell's Copy-item:

> copy-item C:\DirA -Destination C:\DirB -Recurse

OR

> cp C:\DirA -Destination C:\DirB -Recurse

Comment: The Linux cp command also functions as an alias for copy-item.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be:

> xcopy C:\DirA\* C:\DirB\DirA /e /s

Or say your had the folder set as var %foo% in a batch *for* script

> xcopy C:\%foo%\* C:\DirB\%foo%\ /e /s

**EDIT:**

Also if you are happy to use powershell over Command Prompt

> Copy-Item c:\DirA c:\DirB -recurse

Comment: So I have to explicitly specify the source root folder name in the target path as well? Does Windows not have an equivalent to linux's copy -R /mypath /another_existing_path ?

Comment: Not that I know of from cmd - for reference [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Powershell does.

Comment: David beat me to it `Copy-Item c:\DirA c:\DirB -recurse`

Comment: Ah, I just posted that as an answer.

Comment: Yer but your's has correct syntax although mine will work it's not 100% correct :) `-Destination` was missing but will still run without it

Comment: Yes, the -destination parameter is not required if you use positional parameters. I think -r may also substitute for spelling out -recurse. I like using the ISE with Powershell 3.0, as it includes Intellisense, so if you start typing out a command or parameter, it will give you a list of options.

Comment: Your call mate, just glad it worked out well for you